# Settings Activity being overlapped by Action Bar

Tags: android

I am working on Android project and I've created a new Settings Activity from Android. When I created the activity, and tried running, it the Settings Activity that Android Studio created, didn't include an action bar for some reason. I googled around and found that it seems to be a common thing and add the action bar manually, so I've done the following:

```
 private void setupActionBar()
    {
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.toolbar, (ViewGroup)findViewById(android.R.id.content));
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null)
        {
            // Show the Up button in the action bar.
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }
```

I found that the first preference header is hidden under the action bar, again Googled around, found you need to add padding to the list view which I did using the following in the onCreate()

```
getListView().setPadding(0, 180, 0, 0);
```

Doing the above seems a little odd, and it only works on the initial settings activity screen with the list of preference headers. Once you click on the preference headers to view the settings, the first setting is hidden under the action bar as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: view of settings hiding under action bar]

Comment: Can you post your layout file?

Comment: Instead of adding the action bar programmatically, set it using styles. In that way, your design won't break. Also the padding you applied seems hacky. It will break your design.

Comment: @Abhi It felt hacky to me as well, just what a few others said on some other posts. How do you set it in styles, there doesn't seem to be a setContentView, just the XML files for the preference headers, and the xml for the settings. The classes and XML was automatically generated by Android Studio. Min SDK is 15

Comment: @Boardy I was going to add an answer but the answer by AdamSmith is the default implementation of Android Studio to create an Action Bar. It can be used easily and then style it using `styles.xml`. You won't have to set padding using this method. Have you tried it?

Comment: @Abhi It doesn't look to be the default android studio implementation. I right clicked on the project add activity > Settings activity and there was no action bar at all

Comment: @Boardy It seems you have set up a full screen or blank activity app. While creating the project, if a basic layout is selected, the Action Bar shows up and AS implements it using that way.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out.

I created a toolbar XML as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/settings_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Then in the SettingsActivity in the setupActionBar method as below:

```
private void setupActionBar()
    {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.action_bar_root);
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.settings_toolbar, rootView, false);
        rootView.addView(view, 0);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.settings_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            // Show the Up button in the action bar.
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to remove your Action Bar and make a custom toolbar which will be described by other layout file and will contain a widget that cancels your current activity.

For example:

```
  <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/relLayout1">

        <include layout="@layout/snippet_comments_toolbar"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/relLayout2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relLayout1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/listView"></ListView>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

and then snippet_comments_toolbar which is that toolbar I am talking about:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/white_grey_border_bottom"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/profileToolBar">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:id="@+id/backArrow"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_backarrow"/>


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Comments"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/backArrow"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:id="@+id/tvNext"
                    />




            </RelativeLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>



    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</merge>
```